# How to remove the <anyType xsi:type="my type"> from xml output

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a service that takes in line data text and parses the data into XML format.  The service is working, however on the output I am getting "anyType xsi:type="R0001" rather than just R0001 for the node.  I have tried out several suggestions I found on StackOverflow yet none of them seems to work for my code.  Would anyone have any suggestions?  Please see the provided examples:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Client_Data_Parser
{
    public class Records
    {
        public List<Record> WCErecords { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0001))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0002))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0003))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0004))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0005))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0006))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(R0007))]
    [Serializable()]
    public class Record
    {
        public List<object> DataSet { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable()]
    public class R0001
    {
        public string RecKey { get; set; }
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string FormRelationCode { get; set; }
        public string RecipientCode { get; set; }
        public string ClaimType { get; set; }
        public string PullCode { get; set; }
        public string SendToName { get; set; }
        public string SentToAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string SendToAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string SendToCity { get; set; }
        public string SendToState { get; set; }
        public string SendToZip { get; set; }
        public string ForeignCountry { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
        public string MailID { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0002
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string InsuredSeqNum { get; set; }
        public string RunNumSeq { get; set; }
        public string DraftCode { get; set; }
        public string PreauthorizationFlag { get; set; }
        public string MemberName { get; set; }
        public string MemberSSN { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantAddress3 { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantCountry { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantName { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantDOB { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantsNumber { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantsAcctNum { get; set; }
        public string ClaimantsRelation { get; set; }
        public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
        public string ExaminerCode { get; set; }
        public string ExaminerName { get; set; }
        public string ReceivedDate { get; set; }
        public string EntryDate { get; set; }
        public string ReleasedDate { get; set; }
        public string DISDailyBenefitRate { get; set; }
        public string DISWeeklyBenefitRate { get; set; }
        public string DISType { get; set; }
        public string DISBenefitDays { get; set; }
        public string DISBenefitWeeks { get; set; }
        public string DISInjuryDate { get; set; }
        public string DISBackToWorkDate { get; set; }
        public string DISLastWorkDate { get; set; }
        public string DISLastBenefitDate { get; set; }
        public string DIS_YTDTotalAmount { get; set; }
        public string ProviderTIN { get; set; }
        public string BillingProviderName { get; set; }
        public string ServiceProviderName { get; set; }
        public string ProviderAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string ProviderAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string ProviderAddress3 { get; set; }
        public string ProviderCountry { get; set; }
        public string FundCode { get; set; }
        public string FundName { get; set; }
        public string FundAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string FundAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string FundAddress3 { get; set; }
        public string GroupCode { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string GroupAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string GroupAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string GroupAddress3 { get; set; }
        public string Subgroup { get; set; }
        public string SubgroupName { get; set; }
        public string Local { get; set; }
        public string BenefitPlanCode { get; set; }
        public string BenefitPlanDescription { get; set; }
        public string CoverageCode { get; set; }
        public string CoverageDescription { get; set; }
        public string AgentCode { get; set; }
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
        public string EmployerCode { get; set; }
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
        public string ClaimAssignment { get; set; }
        public string PrintDate { get; set; }    
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0003
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string InsuredSeqNum { get; set; }
        public string LineItemNum { get; set; }
        public string FromDate { get; set; }
        public string ThruDate { get; set; }
        public string ProcedureCode { get; set; }
        public string Modifier { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosisCode1 { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosisCode2 { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosisCode3 { get; set; }
        public string DiagnosisCode4 { get; set; }
        public string ToothSurface1 { get; set; }
        public string ToothSurface2 { get; set; }
        public string ToothSurface3 { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
        public string Billed { get; set; }
        public string TotalLineItemIneligAmt { get; set; }
        public string PayType1 { get; set; }
        public string PayType2 { get; set; }
        public string PayType3 { get; set; }
        public string DiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public string CoveredAmount { get; set; }
        public string PlanAllowedAmount1 { get; set; }
        public string PlanAllowedAmount2 { get; set; }
        public string PlanAllowedAmount3 { get; set; }
        public string DeductibleType1 { get; set; }
        public string DeductibleType2 { get; set; }
        public string DeductibleType3 { get; set; }
        public string Deductible1 { get; set; }
        public string Deductible2 { get; set; }
        public string Deductible3 { get; set; }
        public string NetAllowed1 { get; set; }
        public string NetAllowed2 { get; set; }
        public string NetAllowed3 { get; set; }
        public string CoinsuranceRate1 { get; set; }
        public string CoinsuranceRate2 { get; set; }
        public string CoinsuranceRate3 { get; set; }
        public string GrossCovered1 { get; set; }
        public string GrossCovered2 { get; set; }
        public string GrossCovered3 { get; set; }
        public string COBAdjustment1 { get; set; }
        public string COBAdjustment2 { get; set; }
        public string COBAdjustment3 { get; set; }
        public string NetCovered1 { get; set; }
        public string NetCovered2 { get; set; }
        public string NetCovered3 { get; set; }
        public string NetCoveredDiscount { get; set; }
        public string LineItemPaid { get; set; }
        public string PatientLiabilityAmount { get; set; }
        public string ProviderLiabilityAmount { get; set; }
        public string FSALiabilityAmount { get; set; }
        public string PrepaidInsured { get; set; }
        public string PrepaidOtherInsurance { get; set; }
        public string PrepaidMedicare { get; set; }
        public string PPOcode { get; set; }
        public string PPOdescription { get; set; }
        public string DISGrossBenefit { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType1 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription1 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount1 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType2 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription2 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount2 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType3 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription3 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount3 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType4 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription4 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount4 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType5 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription5 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount5 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType6 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription6 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount6 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType7 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription7 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount7 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType8 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription8 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount8 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType9 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription9 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount9 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType10 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingDescription10 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount10 { get; set; }
        public string DISNetBenefitDue { get; set; }
        public string DISTotalPayable { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode1 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode2 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode3 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode4 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode5 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode6 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode7 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode8 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode9 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode10 { get; set; }
        public string AmountNotCoveredByInsurance { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0004
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string InsuredSeqNum { get; set; }
        public string TotalBilled { get; set; }
        public string TotalLineItemIneligAmt { get; set; }
        public string TotalDiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public string TotalCoveredAmount { get; set; }
        public string TotalPlanAllowedAmount { get; set; }
        public string TotalDeductible { get; set; }
        public string TotalNetAllowed { get; set; }
        public string TotalGrossCovered { get; set; }
        public string TotalCOBadjustment { get; set; }
        public string TotalNetCovered { get; set; }
        public string TotalNetCoveredDiscount { get; set; }
        public string TotalPatientLiabilityAmt { get; set; }
        public string TotalProviderLiability { get; set; }
        public string TotalFSAliabilityAmount { get; set; }
        public string TotalPrepaidInsured { get; set; }
        public string TotalPrepaidOther { get; set; }
        public string TotalPrepaidMedicare { get; set; }
        public string TotalPriorPmtAdjustment { get; set; }
        public string TotalPaidPlan1 { get; set; }
        public string TotalPaidPlan2 { get; set; }
        public string TotalPaid { get; set; }
        public string DISGrossBenefit { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType1 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount1 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType2 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount2 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType3 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount3 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType4 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount4 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType5 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount5 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType6 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount6 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType7 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount7 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType8 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount8 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType9 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount9 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingType10 { get; set; }
        public string DISWithholdingAmount10 { get; set; }
        public string DISNetBenefitDue { get; set; }
        public string DISTotalPayable { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode1 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode2 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode3 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode4 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode5 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode6 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode7 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode8 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode9 { get; set; }
        public string LineItemRemarkCode10 { get; set; }
        public string DISContinuationFormFlag { get; set; }
        public string AmountNotCoveredByInsurance { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0005
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string InsuredSeqNum { get; set; }
        public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
        public string LineItemNumber { get; set; }
        public string CommentRemarkCode { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0006
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string InsuredSeqNum { get; set; }
        public string PayeeName { get; set; }
        public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
        public string CheckAmount { get; set; }
        public string CheckDate { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class R0007
    {
        public string RecordType { get; set; }
        public string ABFKey { get; set; }
        public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
        public string CheckAmount { get; set; }
        public string CheckDate { get; set; }
        public string MicrCheckNumber { get; set; }
        public string MicrOnusNumber { get; set; }
        public string MicrTransitNumber { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string BankAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string BankAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string BankCityStateZip { get; set; }
        public string BankCountry { get; set; }
        public string PayeeTIN { get; set; }
        public string PayeeName { get; set; }
        public string PayeeAddress1 { get; set; }
        public string PayeeAddress2 { get; set; }
        public string PayeeCityStateZip { get; set; }
        public string PayeeCountry { get; set; }
        public string CheckAmountText { get; set; }
        public string FractionalRoutingNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a list of objects with class "Record" with each of the record types corresponding to it.  Each "Record" gets added to the "Records" class list yet on output my XML looks like :

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <WCErecords>
    <Record>
      <DataSet>
        <anyType xsi:type="R0001">
          <RecKey>0000000201612191200000304</RecKey>
          <RecordType>0001</RecordType>
          <ABFKey>0000000201612191200000304</ABFKey>
          <FormRelationCode>001</FormRelationCode>
          <RecipientCode>P </RecipientCode>
          <ClaimType>MED</ClaimType>
          <PullCode>  </PullCode>
          <SendToName>SETH L IVINS MD</SendToName>
          <SentToAddress1>PO BOX 71256</SentToAddress1>
          <SendToAddress2 />
          <SendToCity>PHILA</SendToCity>
          <SendToState>PA</SendToState>
          <SendToZip>19176</SendToZip>
          <ForeignCountry />
          <EmailAddress />
          <FaxNumber>          </FaxNumber>
          <MailID>                              </MailID>
        </anyType>
       </DataSet>
    </Record>
  </WCErecords>
</Records>
```

If any additional information or code is required just let me know.  The above XML is just a sample containing just one data type so as not to overwhelm the page with a lot of text.  So what I am looking for is to remove the "anyType xsi:type" and have it just read "R0001".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add attribute `XmlArrayItem` for each possible type in your collection like:

```
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(R0001), ElementName = "R0001")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(R0002), ElementName = "R0002")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(R0003), ElementName = "R0003")]
public List<object> DataSet { get; set; }
```